# CSS navigation - won't stay open on sub-item menus as cursor rolls off :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56cx8zwx/5/) and you'll see the issue quickly.

I'm using `:hover` for my sub-items in my CSS menu. When I hover on the sub items, I can no longer get to the "item three" as the size of the container reduces, and my cursor position is no longer hovering.

How would you solve this? Is there a pure CSS solution?

The sub-item display works by using the `.has-children` class:

```css
#menu li.has-children:hover ul#sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Alek that is the same link as my JSFiddle, what exactly is the solution you mention?

Comment: The problem is that the amount of items being shown when you hover over them is the same amount of items below, so when you move the hover away from those 2 new shown items, you are right at where your list ends regularly. perhaps use CSS transitions to give the user time to move their mouse?

Comment: hi there :)

i'm no pro with CSS but how about you just show the sub items at right of it instead of below the items

Comment: @Cedie because that's not how the design works

Comment: Quick thing, unless you know that there will never be a submenu in another field, I wouldn't recommend the ID specific CSS styling you have. Something with classes or even just the fact that there is a child ul should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, **here's a workaround** : try simply to put some padding at the bottom of your #main-navigation element.
It will provide some space where the cursor will still trigger the :hover state.

```
#main-navigation {padding-bottom: 20px}
```

There : http://jsfiddle.net/56cx8zwx/12/

*I cleaned a bit your code, some hover rules weren't necessary.*

*But well, assuming you'll give some styles to your menu (padding to the LIs, etc.), I guess you won't need this.*

Comment: Hi, I did try with the padding. The problem is that the menu has a  background colour so it shows as this padding as a big long menu :(

Comment: Can you give a live example of this ? In this case, I think you just need to change the hover state to a parent element. In the example I gave, there's no such thing, so feel free to copy and paste :)